# Kotlin - DSL Color Style

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-dsl

When you annotate an annotation class in Kotlin with @DslMarker, an icon appears in the gutter indicating the DSL style

[image]

When I try to change the style to a different color it doesn't do anything. How does Kotlin choose the DSL style, and how do I enforce a particular style?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are only four predefined DSL styles for which you can customize the display options.

For each `@DslMarker` annotation, the IDE chooses one of the predefined styles using a hash function of the annotation's fully qualified name. This style is then used for highlighting the usages of functions marked with the annotation. The purpose of the different styles is that different DSLs (marked by different `@DslMarker` annotations) are less likely to visually clash.

Moving an annotation's declaration in the source file relative to the other annotations won't affect its chosen style, but renaming it may lead to a different style being chosen for the annotation.

This style is selected in the settings dialog when you click the gutter icon of a `@DslMarker annotation class`.

Here's an example of how it works.

[image]

You can see that the `Style3` is chosen for two annotation classes at once. There's currently no way to force the IDE to choose a particular style for an annotation class.

---

UPD: the implementation sources in the Kotlin IDE plugin code can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f9012cf63747dbd2edc92631ebdd8b9c61d91e27/idea/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/highlighter/markers/DslHighlightingMarker.kt#L59) and [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/65244b4bea81f737466618927d4f3afe339cad0d/idea/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/highlighter/dsl/DslHighlighterExtension.kt#L52).

Comment: Do you have any more details on the style selection algorithm, beyond the hash function? I know it would be bad practice to pick names because they yield a particular style, but I’m just curious as to how the hash function maps to the styles.

Comment: @series0ne: I've added a link to the implementation of this feature in the Kotlin IDE plugin sources, see the UPD. (the implementation in one screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl472.png)

Comment: I tried several string combinations and if you suffix your annotations with numbers it will generate the 4 different hashes:


`@DslMarker 
annotation class MyDsl1 // purple`

`@DslMarker 
annotation class MyDsl2 // aquamarine`

`@DslMarker 
annotation class MyDsl3 // chartreuse green`

`@DslMarker 
annotation class MyDsl4 // orange`